# Stop old tabs & Reload new tabs when click

Tags: jquery, tabs

i create 2 tabs: Tabs 1 & Tabs 2. I use visual composer to create tabs

```
/* =========================================================
 * vc-tabs.js v1.0.0
 * =========================================================
 * Copyright 2013 Wpbakery
 *
 * Visual composer Tabs
 * ========================================================= */
+ function ( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    var Tabs, old, clickHandler, changeHandler;

    /**
     * Tabs object definition
     * @param element
     * @constructor
     */
    Tabs = function ( element, options ) {
        this.$element = $( element );
        this.activeClass = 'vc_active';
        this.tabSelector = '[data-vc-tab]';

        // cached vars
        this.useCacheFlag = undefined;
        this.$target = undefined;
        this.selector = undefined;
        this.$targetTab = undefined;
        this.$relatedAccordion = undefined;
        this.$container = undefined;
    };

    /**
     * Is cache used
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.isCacheUsed = function () {
        var useCache, that;
        that = this;
        useCache = function () {
            return false !== that.$element.data( 'vcUseCache' );
        };

        if ( undefined === this.useCacheFlag ) {
            this.useCacheFlag = useCache();
        }

        return this.useCacheFlag;
    };

    /**
     * Get container
     * @returns {*|Number}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.getContainer = function () {
        if ( ! this.isCacheUsed() ) {
            return this.findContainer();
        }

        if ( undefined === this.$container ) {
            this.$container = this.findContainer();
        }

        return this.$container;
    };

    /**
     * Find container
     * @returns {window.jQuery}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.findContainer = function () {
        var $container;
        $container = this.$element.closest( this.$element.data( 'vcContainer' ) );
        if ( ! $container.length ) {
            $container = $( 'body' );
        }
        return $container;
    };

    /**
     * Get container accordions
     * @returns {*}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.getContainerAccordion = function () {
        return this.getContainer().find( '[data-vc-accordion]' );
    };

    /**
     * Get selector
     * @returns {*}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.getSelector = function () {
        var findSelector, $this;

        $this = this.$element;
        findSelector = function () {
            var selector;

            selector = $this.data( 'vcTarget' );
            if ( ! selector ) {
                selector = $this.attr( 'href' );
            }

            return selector;
        };

        if ( ! this.isCacheUsed() ) {
            return findSelector();
        }

        if ( undefined === this.selector ) {
            this.selector = findSelector();
        }

        return this.selector;
    };

    /**
     * Get target
     * @returns {*}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.getTarget = function () {
        var selector;
        selector = this.getSelector();

        if ( ! this.isCacheUsed() ) {
            return this.getContainer().find( selector );
        }

        if ( undefined === this.$target ) {
            this.$target = this.getContainer().find( selector );
        }

        return this.$target;
    };

    /**
     * Get related accordion
     * @returns {*}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.getRelatedAccordion = function () {
        var tab, filterElements;

        tab = this;

        filterElements = function () {
            var $elements;

            $elements = tab.getContainerAccordion().filter( function () {
                var $that, accordion;
                $that = $( this );

                accordion = $that.data( 'vc.accordion' );

                if ( undefined === accordion ) {
                    $that.vcAccordion();
                    accordion = $that.data( 'vc.accordion' );
                }

                return tab.getSelector() === accordion.getSelector();
            } );

            if ( $elements.length ) {
                return $elements;
            }

            return undefined;
        };
        if ( ! this.isCacheUsed() ) {
            return filterElements();
        }

        if ( undefined === this.$relatedAccordion ) {
            this.$relatedAccordion = filterElements();
        }

        return this.$relatedAccordion;
    };

    /**
     * Trigger event
     * @param event
     */
    Tabs.prototype.triggerEvent = function ( event ) {
        var $event;
        if ( 'string' === typeof event ) {
            $event = $.Event( event );
            this.$element.trigger( $event );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Get target tab
     * @returns {*|Number}
     */
    Tabs.prototype.getTargetTab = function () {
        var $this;
        $this = this.$element;

        if ( ! this.isCacheUsed() ) {
            return $this.closest( this.tabSelector );
        }

        if ( undefined === this.$targetTab ) {
            this.$targetTab = $this.closest( this.tabSelector );
        }

        return this.$targetTab;
    };

    /**
     * Tab Clicked
     */
    Tabs.prototype.tabClick = function () {

        this.getRelatedAccordion().trigger( 'click' );
    };

    /**
     * Tab Show
     */
    Tabs.prototype.show = function () {
        // if showed no need to do anything
        if ( this.getTargetTab().hasClass( this.activeClass ) ) {
            return;
        }

        this.triggerEvent( 'show.vc.tab' );

        this.getTargetTab().addClass( this.activeClass );
    };

    /**
     * Tab Hide
     */
    Tabs.prototype.hide = function () {
        // if showed no need to do anything
        if ( ! this.getTargetTab().hasClass( this.activeClass ) ) {
            return;
        }

        this.triggerEvent( 'hide.vc.tab' );

        this.getTargetTab().removeClass( this.activeClass );
    };

    //Tabs.prototype

    // Tabs plugin definition
    // ==========================
    function Plugin( action, options ) {
        var args;

        args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        return this.each( function () {
            var $this, data;

            $this = $( this );
            data = $this.data( 'vc.tabs' );
            if ( ! data ) {
                data = new Tabs( $this, $.extend( true, {}, options ) );
                $this.data( 'vc.tabs', data );
            }
            if ( 'string' === typeof action ) {
                data[ action ].apply( data, args );
            }
        } );
    }

    old = $.fn.vcTabs;

    $.fn.vcTabs = Plugin;
    $.fn.vcTabs.Constructor = Tabs;

    // Tabs no conflict
    // ==========================
    $.fn.vcTabs.noConflict = function () {
        $.fn.vcTabs = old;
        return this;
    };

    // Tabs data-api
    // =================

    clickHandler = function ( e ) {
        var $this;
        $this = $( this );
        e.preventDefault();
        Plugin.call( $this, 'tabClick' );
    };

    changeHandler = function ( e ) {
        var caller;
        caller = $( e.target ).data( 'vc.accordion' );

        if ( undefined === caller.getRelatedTab ) {
            /**
             * Get related tab from accordion
             * @returns {*}
             */
            caller.getRelatedTab = function () {
                var findTargets;

                findTargets = function () {
                    var $targets;
                    $targets = caller.getContainer().find( '[data-vc-tabs]' ).filter( function () {
                        var $this, tab;
                        $this = $( this );

                        tab = $this.data( 'vc.accordion' );
                        if ( undefined === tab ) {
                            $this.vcAccordion();
                        }
                        tab = $this.data( 'vc.accordion' );

                        return tab.getSelector() === caller.getSelector();
                    } );

                    return $targets;
                };

                if ( ! caller.isCacheUsed() ) {
                    return findTargets();
                }

                if ( undefined === caller.relatedTab ) {
                    caller.relatedTab = findTargets();
                }

                return caller.relatedTab;
            };
        }

        Plugin.call( caller.getRelatedTab(), e.type );
    };

    $( document ).on( 'click.vc.tabs.data-api', '[data-vc-tabs]', clickHandler );
    $( document ).on( 'show.vc.accordion hide.vc.accordion', changeHandler );
}( window.jQuery );
```

Html

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row td-pb-row"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span12">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper"><div class="vc_tta-container" data-vc-action="collapse">
        <div class="vc_general vc_tta vc_tta-tabs vc_tta-color-grey vc_tta-style-classic vc_tta-shape-rounded vc_tta-spacing-1 vc_tta-tabs-position-top vc_tta-controls-align-left">
            <div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
                <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
                    <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab><a href="#1446604677128-25463b2a-f24d" data-vc-tabs data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 1</span></a></li>
                    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab><a href="#1446604677478-7e69336f-9679" data-vc-tabs data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 2</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <div class="vc_tta-panels-container">
        <div class="vc_tta-panels">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel vc_active" id="1446604677128-25463b2a-f24d" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
                <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading"><h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#1446604677128-25463b2a-f24d" data-vc-accordion data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 1</span></a></h4></div>
                    <div class="vc_tta-panel-body">
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <p>I am text block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel" id="1446604677478-7e69336f-9679" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body"><div class="vc_tta-panel-heading"><h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#1446604677478-7e69336f-9679" data-vc-accordion data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Tab 2</span></a></h4></div>
                <div class="vc_tta-panel-body">
                    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <p>I am text block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

How to: Tabs 1 stop & Tabs 2 reload content when i click on Tabs 2 and Tabs 2 stop & Tabs 1 reload content when i click on Tabs 1

Demo like this website: http://www.fullmatchesandshows.com/2015/11/03/borussia-moenchengladbach-vs-juventus-highlights-full-match/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you think by 'reload content', but you can fire things on tab shown like this:

```
$(document).on('show.vc.accordion', function() {
    console.log('shown tab');
});
```

Comment: This fires accordions and tabs, he needs only tabs.